# oracle query to populate different columns into one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

What should be oracle query to populate three different columns value from single row to three different rows in single column along with one column generated on-fly and result should not include null value in column

Table: Telecom
**id ---   provider ---    consumer  --- receiver**
 1  ----vodaphone ----    t-mobile -----  AT&T

expected out is
**id -----  name  ----       type**
1  ----  vodaphone----    provider
1  ----  t-mobile ----    consumer
1 ----   AT&T     --------    reciever

Answer (score 0):

A simple way uses `union all`:

```
select id, provider as name, 'provider' from telecom union all
select id, consumer, 'consumer' from telecom union all
select id, receiver, 'receiver' from telecom ;
```

This will scan `telecom` three times.  A more efficient method might be:

```
select t.id,
       (case which when 'provider' then provider
                   when 'consumer' then consumer
                   when 'receiver' then receiver
        end) as name,
       which                  
from telecom t cross join
     (select 'provider' as which from dual union all
      select 'consumer' as which from dual union all
      select 'receiver' as which from dual
     ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

CREATE TABLE Telecom ( id, provider, consumer, receiver ) AS
SELECT 1, 'vodaphone', 't-mobile', 'AT&T' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       "type"
FROM   telecom
UNPIVOT( name FOR "type" IN ( provider, consumer, receiver ) );
```

**Output**:

```
       ID NAME      type   
---------- --------- --------
         1 vodaphone PROVIDER 
         1 t-mobile  CONSUMER 
         1 AT&T      RECEIVER
```

**Update**:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

CREATE TABLE Telecom ( id, col_provider, col_consumer, col_receiver ) AS
SELECT 1, 'vodaphone', 't-mobile', 'AT&T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 't-mobile',  NULL, 'EE' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       "type"
FROM   telecom
UNPIVOT( name FOR "type" IN ( col_provider AS 'provider',
                              col_consumer AS 'consumer',
                              col_receiver AS 'receiver' ) );
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME      type   
---------- --------- --------
         1 vodaphone provider 
         1 t-mobile  consumer 
         1 AT&T      receiver 
         1 t-mobile  provider 
         1 EE        receiver
```

Comment: would it ignore to create row for empty column?. What about if our column name are different for type e.g COL_Provider, COL_Consumer, COL_RECEIVER but want out put in type as given above